# How do I create an email subdomain on Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I would like to create an email sub-domain so that we can separate out marketing emails from transactional emails.

We are using Route53 and we have an MX set up at company.com and would like to add a email subdomain for marketing.company.com. Is this just creating a new MX record using the same values as company.com or am I creating a CNAME record for that domain specifically and pointing it back to company.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an MX record for `marketing` in Route 53, using the same servers used for the company.  Make sure you have setup your mail server as needed, then send emails to anyone@marketing.company.com.

You won't need a CNAME, as the MX record will resolve properly as is.